# Struggling to make my data transmission work reliably at even 2bps

Tags: python, fft, data-transfer

I'm building a data transmission system via "inaudible" frequencies, but the best result so far was a 6% bit loss, transmitting 450B, at the speed of 2bps. I don't know much about data transmission and it's my first project in Python.

Sending in the form of asynchronous communication would in theory allow for lossless transmission, so I have no clue as to why is it losing bits of data on low speeds such as 2bps. Here is the code for the receiving part, I've tested the transmission one with external devices and it works accurately and fine :/

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import pylab
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys
import seaborn as sns
import time

class Fourier():

    def __init__(self):
        print("Fourier class constructed\n")

    #Random variables
    received_data = ""
    #i=0
    #f,ax = plt.subplots(2)
    #Default value, gets changed according to set_reading_speed()
    speed = 1
    count = 0
    #Preparing the Plotting Environment with random starting values
    #x = np.arange(10000)
    #y = np.random.randn(10000)

    #Raw audio data plot
    #li, = ax[0].plot(x, y)
    #ax[0].set_xlim(0,4000)
    #ax[0].set_ylim(-20000,20000)
    #ax[0].set_title("Raw Audio Signal")

    #FFT plot
    #li2, = ax[1].plot(x, y)
    #ax[1].set_xlim(0,20000)
    #ax[1].set_ylim(-50,100)
    #ax[1].set_title("Fast Fourier Transform")

    #Show the plot, but without blocking updates
    #plt.pause(0.01)
    #plt.tight_layout()

    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    CHUNK = 2048
    RECORD_SECONDS = 0.1
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    #Start Recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE,
                        input=True)#,
                        #frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    stream.start_stream() #Opens the connection and start streaming the data

    result_herz = 0 #Making the variable visible to other class methods

    pass_flag = False #Makes sure we read the first available bit after waiting for the start bit to end
    timeout_flag = False #False until no more bits are received in a timespan of 5 seconds
    data_flag = False #Marks the start of reading data from the channel
    start_flag = False #True while the start bit is detected
    listening_start = time.time() #Making both variables visible
    timeout_start = time.time()
    self.data_flag=False

    def check_timeout(self):
        timeout_end = time.time()
        if (timeout_end - self.timeout_start) > 5.0:
            self.timeout_flag = True
            print("Listener has timed out")
            print("Received {} bits".format(self.count))

    def listen(self):
        #For determining when to read another bit
        self.listening_start = time.time()
        #To determine if timeout_flag should be raised
        self.timeout_start = time.time()
        while not self.timeout_flag:
            #to measure time spent running a cycle
            #start_time = time.clock()
            self.calc() #Picks up data from the microphone and calculates the frequency
            self.check_timeout() #Checks if 5 seconds have passed since the last bit received
            #end_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 5)
            #print(end_time)

    def plot(self, audio_data, dfft):
        #Plotting data, for it to function the lines of code right under the constructor should be uncommented
        self.li.set_xdata(np.arange(len(audio_data)))
        self.li.set_ydata(audio_data)
        self.li2.set_xdata(np.arange(len(dfft))*10.)
        self.li2.set_ydata(dfft)
        plt.pause(0.01)

    def calc(self):
        input_data = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK) #Read the stream
        audio_data = np.fromstring(input_data, np.int16) #Acquire and convert data to floats
        dfft = 10.*np.log10(abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_data))) #FFT, 10*log10(abs) is to scale it to dB and make sure its not imaginary
        fft_bin = np.fft.fftfreq(len(dfft)) #Calculating the frequencies
        idx = np.argmax(np.abs(dfft)) #Finding the peak in the coefficients
        fft_bin = fft_bin[idx]
        self.result_herz = abs(fft_bin*self.RATE) #Final result
        self.check_frequenc() #Checks frequency
        #print(result_herz)
        #self.plot(audio_data, dfft) #Update the graph

    def check_frequenc(self):
        #Asynchronous data receiving
        if self.result_herz > 14900.0 and self.result_herz < 15100.0: #Checks if it is the start bit
            self.data_flag = False #We don't read data from the start bit
            self.start_flag = True #Signals that the start bit is active
            #print("count reset")
            #self.stream.stop_stream()
            #self.stream.start_stream()
            self.timeout_start = time.time() #Starts the timeout timer
            #print("if n1")

        if self.start_flag == True: #If start bit is active
            #print("if n2")
            if not (self.result_herz > 14900.0 and self.result_herz < 15100.0): #Checks if the start bit is still here
                #print("end of start bit")
                self.start_flag = False
                self.data_flag = True #Allows for reading data
                self.pass_flag = True #Allows for the first bit we arrive on to be instantly read, after that we read once every self.read

        if self.data_flag == True:
            #print("if n3")
            listening_end = time.time()
            if ((listening_end - self.listening_start) >= self.speed) or self.pass_flag: #Checks the timestamps
                self.pass_flag = False #Turn off the pass_flag, it gets activated every 8 bits received
                #print("reading")
                if self.result_herz > 18700.0 and self.result_herz < 18800.0: #Check for ranges
                    #print("read")
                    self.set_data('1') #Write to self.received_data
                    self.timeout_start = time.time() #Reset timeout timer
                    self.listening_start = time.time() #Reset listening timer
                if self.result_herz > 19150.0 and self.result_herz < 19250.0:
                    #print("read")
                    self.set_data('0')
                    self.timeout_start = time.time()
                    self.listening_start = time.time()
        #if not self.data_flag:
            #if self.result_herz > 14900.0 and self.result_herz < 15100.0:
                #self.start_flag=True
            #elif self.start_flag:
                #self.data_flag=true

    def reset_count(self): #Resets the flags and sleeps for half the interval of transmission, to land somewhere near the middle of the signal
        #print("count reset")
        self.start_flag = False
        self.data_flag = False
        time.sleep(self.speed/2.0) #Sleep ends up being called every new Byte of data, so we align ourselves on the first bit

    def set_data(self, value):
        if value == '1':
            self.received_data = self.received_data + '1'
        if value == '0':
            self.received_data = self.received_data + '0'
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if self.count % 8 == 0: #Checks if it is time to sleeps to get in sync
            self.reset_count()

    def set_reading_speed(self, s):
        self.speed = s #Received speed
        print("Listening speed is: {}".format(self.speed))

    def __del__(self): #Destructor
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.audio.terminate()

    def get_data(self):
        return self.received_data #Data passing
```

Occasionally, I get a RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10,
which comes from line 102 | dfft = 10.*np.log10(abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_data)))

Comment: Am I looking at code for reception or transmissiont? When testing do you actually use hardware? Up untill the point you have the software working I suggest not to use any hardware and fake it between the transmitting and receiving code. Feeding the perfect output as perfect input.

Comment: It is the code for reception. I'll look into faking transmission right now, thanks

Comment: Any links on how to test the software without the hardware?

Comment: check out [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) for python and design your software such that the signal modulation and demodulation code does not depend on hardware. Isolate hardware calls in sperate classes. When testing without hardware mock thoses classes

Comment: yeah, done, turns out my seemingly okay receiver code does not perform well and keeps falling out of sync